# calculate percentage in a data frame R

Tags: r, statistics, percentage

I have a data frame of multiple columns. I want to create a new colomns with the percentage. I don't have the correct output, any suggestions?

```
il.count.descrition elle.count.description un.count.description   Words.count
     5                      1                      5                    563
     9                      2                      2                    65
     1                      1                      4                    100
     10                     9                      0                    89
```

```
data %>% mutate(il.count.ratio = il.count.description / Words.count * 100,
                elle.count.ratio = elle.count.description / Words.count * 100,
                un.count.ratio = un.count.description / Words.count * 100)
```

Comment: What is the error you have gotten? Is it cause by the typo between `il.count.descrition` and `il.count.description`? Would also be better if you not multiply 100 for a ratio. If you need to display it as percentage, consider `scales::percent`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this, it works for me. Maybe the error is because you have a typo in the first variable name.

```
data <- data %>% mutate(il.count.ratio = round(il.count.descrition / Words.count * 100,1),
                elle.count.ratio = round(elle.count.description / Words.count * 100,1),
                un.count.ratio = round(un.count.description / Words.count * 100,1))
```

Comment: Isaac Bravo thank you, it works now